# Does module names reside in a separate "name space", or could they collide with e.g. variable names?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I guess/hope that module names will not collide with e.g. names of variables. Could someone confirm this, and perhaps reference a suitable section in the (upcoming) standard?

File: a_module.cc

```
export module a_module;
export int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

// Question-1: Is using 'a_module' below as variable name allowed, or does
// the 'export module a_module' above prevent us from using that name?
int a_module = 11;
```

File: main.cc

```
import a_module;

// Question-2: Is using 'a_module' below as variable name fine, or does the
// 'import a_module' above prevent us from using that name?
int a_module = 42;

int main() { return add(1, 2); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to cite a negative, but yes - module names cannot collide with non-module names.

We have lots and lots of kinds of name lookup in C++, but none of them consider module names. Like the statement `f(x);` can find many kinds of things named `f` and `x` and those `()`s could even mean different things, but it can never find either a *module* named `f` or `x`. Having modules named one or the other or both does not change any of the lookup.

Likewise, in the preamble, all `module`-related statements (`import`, `export`, module declarations or partition declarations) *only* consider module names. If you have something like:

```
import M1;
import M2;
```

And `M1` happens to export some name `M2`, that won't break the subsequent `import` of `M2`. We're only looking for, specifically, `module`s named `M2`.

You don't have to worry about collisions between these two things.